# One stick of memory

Tags: memory, sticky-notes

Can I run a 1-2gb stick by itself in a gx 520 running win7 64 bit. All I have is 2gb stick and I need to up grade my computer that are 520 to win 7 64bit. can I just use one stick in each computer?

Comment: This entirely depends on the motherboard.  I would check the manual to the motherboard for supported memory configurations.

Answer (score 1):

The Dell GX520 motherboard supports pc2-3200 DIMM 240-pin RAM up to 4GB.
You will be able to use a 2GB stick.